# How to test column values in protractor?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation, protractor

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">

        <thead>
        <tr>
        <td>
        <a href="#" ng-click="sortType = 'date'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">
        Date-Time
        </a>
        </td>
        <td><a>Amount</a></td>
        <td><a>Transaction Type</a></td>
    </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>


    <!-- ngRepeat: tx in transactions | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | sDate:startDate:end --><tr id="anchor0" ng-repeat="tx in transactions | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | sDate:startDate:end" class="ng-scope">
        <td class="ng-binding">Dec 13, 2016 10:54:12 AM</td>
    <td class="ng-binding">12</td>
        <td class="ng-binding">Debit</td>
        </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: tx in transactions | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | sDate:startDate:end --><tr id="anchor1" ng-repeat="tx in transactions | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | sDate:startDate:end" class="ng-scope">
        <td class="ng-binding">Dec 13, 2016 10:54:10 AM</td>
    <td class="ng-binding">155</td>
        <td class="ng-binding">Debit</td>
        </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: tx in transactions | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | sDate:startDate:end --><tr id="anchor2" ng-repeat="tx in transactions | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | sDate:startDate:end" class="ng-scope">
        <td class="ng-binding">Dec 13, 2016 10:54:05 AM</td>
    <td class="ng-binding">32</td>
        <td class="ng-binding">Credit</td>
        </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: tx in transactions | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | sDate:startDate:end --><tr id="anchor3" ng-repeat="tx in transactions | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | sDate:startDate:end" class="ng-scope">
        <td class="ng-binding">Dec 13, 2016 10:54:03 AM</td>
    <td class="ng-binding">1000</td>
        <td class="ng-binding">Credit</td>
        </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: tx in transactions | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | sDate:startDate:end --><tr id="anchor4" ng-repeat="tx in transactions | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | sDate:startDate:end" class="ng-scope">
        <td class="ng-binding">Dec 8, 2016 4:45:08 PM</td>
    <td class="ng-binding">100</td>
        <td class="ng-binding">Debit</td>
        </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: tx in transactions | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | sDate:startDate:end --><tr id="anchor5" ng-repeat="tx in transactions | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | sDate:startDate:end" class="ng-scope">
        <td class="ng-binding">Dec 8, 2016 4:44:43 PM</td>
    <td class="ng-binding">210</td>
        <td class="ng-binding">Credit</td>
        </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: tx in transactions | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | sDate:startDate:end -->
    </tbody>

    </table>
```

I am adding sample code which i am trying to test this website.Multiple ways i tried to resolve my problem but failed to solve . Now help me you all to get out of it-

```
it("Column values",function () {
browser.get('http://www.way2automation.com/angularjs-protractor/banking/#/listTx#anchor');
browser.sleep(1500);
var rows = element.all(by.repeater("tx in transactions"));

var data = rows.map(function (row) {
    var cells = row.all("td");
    return {
        value1: cells.first().getText(),
        value2: cells.get(1).getText(),
        value3: cells.get(2).getText()
    }
});

    expect(data).toEqual([
        {value1: "Dec 8, 2016 4:44:43 PM", value2: "210", value3: "Credit"},
        {value1: "Dec 8, 2016 4:45:08 PM", value2: "100", value3: "Debit"}
    ]);
```

I want this values from HTML Dec 8, 2016 4:44:43 PM
210
Credit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to resolve the `getText()` method to obtain the cell value.try something like below,

```
var data = rows.map(function (row) {
   return row.all("td").getText().then(function(cellTextArray){
     return {
       value1: cellTextArray[0],
       value2: cellTextArray[1],
       value3: cellTextArray[2]
    }
  })

});
```

Comment: Expected [  ] to equal  {value1: "Dec 8, 2016 4:44:43 PM", value2: "210", value3: "Credit"},
            {value1: "Dec 8, 2016 4:45:08 PM", value2: "100", value3: "Debit"}
        ]);

Comment: Your locator is wrong. change `row.all("td")` to `row.all(by.css("td"))`

Comment: I tried it from my end and its working fine. Look at the result http://oi67.tinypic.com/14wv97l.jpg